# VBA Label formatting

Tags: forms, vba, text

I am using label from tool box control to place and write a default text to my form. However I want to break line and I don't know how to do it.

I don't believe writing a paragraph on the caption field is the right way to customize my form, is it? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

When you are writing your text into your label press (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) to add a return carriage.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the `vbCrLf` constant to update the caption by code:

```
Label1.Caption = "New" & vbCrLf & "caption"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'vbnewline' to move to the next line in the field, just make sure your label is sized properly so it will show.

Example: string = "Text" & vbnewline & "text"

will read:

Text

text